# ECDSA key and csr with phpseclib

Tags: phpseclib

Does anyone have any information on this or knows if its supported by phpseclib? Or if its in the pipeline?

I am able to genertate key,csr an public key with RSA but would love to be able to do so with ECDSA as that is pretty much the direction of where encryption is headed. More and more Certificate Authorities are starting to adopt this and is supported in both windows and apache servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpseclib has a branch that supports ECDSA keys, i needed to download this specific branch with composer.

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1519

composer require phpseclib/phpseclib:dev-master

```
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib3\File\X509;
use phpseclib3\Crypt\PublicKeyLoader;

$privKey = PublicKeyLoader::load(file_get_contents('/path/to/key.pem'), $password = false);

$x509 = new X509();
$x509->setPrivateKey($privKey);
$x509->setDNProp('id-at-organizationName', 'phpseclib demo cert');

$csr = $x509->signCSR();

echo $x509->saveCSR($csr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. phpseclib only supports RSA atm, although it sounds like ECDSA is in the (long) pipeline:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/37#issuecomment-11647092