# phpseclib ssh login fails with no errors

Tags: ssh, phpseclib

Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

$ssh = new SSH2('stg.net');
$key = new RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('/Users/me/.ssh/my_private_key'));
if (!$ssh->login('username', $key)) {
    print_r($ssh->getLastError());
    print_r($ssh->getErrors());
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
)
```

In `vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php` there is `function _privatekey_login($username, $privatekey)`

```
$publickey = $privatekey->getPublicKey(RSA::PUBLIC_FORMAT_RAW);
if ($publickey === false) {
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting `false`, maybe I have to set public key too? How can it be done?
How to debug it?

+++ UPDATE +++

I tried advices/hints from these tickets too:

[phpseclib always gives login failed with no log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319896/phpseclib-always-gives-login-failed-with-no-log?rq=1)

[Net/SSH2 - phpseclib login failing - error: "failedArray"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769291/net-ssh2-phpseclib-login-failing-error-failedarray)

Comment: What'd be more useful than the errors are the log files. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then `$ssh->getLog()` before the `exit;`. That said, based on your `_privatekey_login` comment it sounds like maybe you're trying to use a DSA or ECDSA key in place of an RSA key. Most RSA private keys include the public key within them and it's hard to imagine you using one that doesn't. I mean, it's not impossible but it is improbable.

Comment: @neubert thank you so much for your comment, you are right I'm using ECDSA key. Is it still not supported?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688283/ecdsa-key-and-csr-with-phpseclib

Comment: A status update on that was posted recently at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1082#issuecomment-396122366 . Quoting it, "_I'm not ready to make my code public yet. I just thought I'd post a progress report for anyone interested_". My guess is that the code changes would be in the master branch, however, and not the 2.0 branch. I say that because the DSA changes were in the master branch and not the 2.0 branch. Eventually the master branch (as I understand it) will become 3.0.0 but idk when that'd happen.

Comment: thank you for your awesome help, you can post it as the answer & I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the key in question is an ECDSA key. Quoting https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1082#issuecomment-396122366 :

> My library supports EdDSA keys in the OpenSSH format (ie. the kind
> that `ssh-keygen` would generate), the PuTTY format (ie. the kind
> `puttygen` would generate), in libsodium format and in the format
> specified in this IETF Draft:
>
> https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-curdle-pkix-07
>
> If libsodium / sodium_compat are being used the keys are converted
> from whatever format they were in to the libsodium format to
> facilitate libsodium's use.
>
> Encrypted OpenSSH private keys are not supported for the same reason
> sodium_compat does not support Argon2i - it's too slow. OpenSSH uses a
> custom form of bcrypt that does bcrypt 128 times as I recall and
> encrypts a different string etc so PHP's bcrypt implementation cannot
> be used and since bcrypt uses a custom key expansion OpenSSL's
> implementation of Blowfish can't be used either.

Here the author is talking about EdDSA - not ECDSA - but from the rest of the post it sounds like ECDSA over prime finite fields is complete as well.

Quoting the post that follows that one:

> Also, I'm not ready to make my code public yet. I just thought I'd post a progress report for anyone interested.

My guess is that this implementation will live in the master branch and not the 2.0 branch. I say that because the DSA changes were in the master branch and not the 2.0 branch. Eventually the master branch (as I understand it) will become 3.0.0 but idk when that'd happen.